# How to execute Startup script before response.redirect?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a page where I am reading the query string. if a certain value exists in querystring I am registering a start up script. after the script is executed, I want to remove the element from querystring and reload the page with the new url.

This is the code which runs in page pre-render event.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Page.Request.QueryString.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this.Page.Request.QueryString[i].Equals("filesize"))
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('Maximum file size exceeded.');", true);

                    var nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString());
                    nameValueCollection.Remove("exception");
                    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path + "?" + nameValueCollection;
                    Response.Redirect(url);
                }
            }
```

But the redirect is taking place before the alert is shown. How can I show the alert, then after closing the alert I can redirect the page?

Answer (score 2):

Since the `Response.Redirect(url)` is sending back an HTTP 302, the browser is likely ignoring any of the body content, so your startup script is not going to execute at all. Some options:

1. You can remove the redirect and insert content to allow the user to
   react to any error messages you are displaying.
2. You can store the error in a session variable and then redirect to
   an error page to display it to the user.